# Python: behaviour of decorator with wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

I don´t understand why the line "cache = {}" is executed only the first time i call the function multiply(x, y). After that, that line is ignored. This makes the program work well, but i don´t understand that behaviour.

```
def memoize(func):

     cache = {}
     print("cache")

     @functools.wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args):
         if args in cache:
             return cache[args]

         result = func(*args)
         cache[args] = result

         return result

     return wrapper

 @memoize
 def multiply(x, y):
     return x * y

 print(multiply(2, 3))
 print(multiply(2, 3))
```

The result is:

```
 cache
 6
 6
```

So the lines "cache = {}" and "print("cache")" were only executed the frist time.
Thanks

Comment: "*the line `cache = {}` is executed the first time i call the function `multiply(x, y)`*" Wrong. That line is execute **before** you ever call `multiply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the decorator code which is "executed everytime" is the wrapper function. The code outside that wrapper function is executed just when the operator is applied -

This nothing magic or "new" - just see the order things are and what is called when - the only thing out of normal execution order which cold be called  just a bit magic is the decoration itself- just remember that:

```
 @memoize
 def multiply(x, y):
     return x * y
```

is just the same thing as:

```
def multiply(x, y):
     return x * y

multiply = memoize(multiply)
```

Also, if you are trying to understand decorators, leave the `functools.wraps` call out of it for now. It is good for production code, and for filling in small details: it disguises your wrapper function as the inner function it decorates (for example, the function `wrapper` `__name__`attribute is set to `multiply` in this example), but is an unnecessary complication when trying to understand decorators.

Comment: With that example i understand now. The line "cache = {}" is executed when the operator is applied. Then only the wrapper function. Thanks

Comment: Also i understand some of the information of the original function is retained with functools.wraps(func).